# No output for loop program

Tags: c#

The scope is to output the numbers from 1 to (input number) with the multiples of 3 being a `*` each. E.g. for 8 as input: 1,2,`*`,4,5,`*`,7,8. I tried to do this with a for loop but it has no output for some reason.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace HelpPleaseStackOverFlow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int x;
            for (x = 1; x <= number; ) 
                if (x % 3 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("*");
                }
                else;
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x); 
                    x = x++;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried converting the x variable (integer) to a string and then making it the * that should be printed out, in the first half of the IF statement and the last part with the ELSE basically the same.

I also tried to make the for statement like this:

```
for (x = 1; x <= number; x++)
```

with the x++ at the end but this just game me the result of *,*,8. With an input of 7; 8 should not be part of this and I have no idea why it put 8 as an output.

Comment: There's a stray `;` after the `else`, so your code isn't what you think it is. (Not the only problem.)

Comment: C# and Python are different languages. Please make sure to read on how those two are different, in particular whether one uses spaces or special characters to indicate beginning and end of [statements block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/statements).

Comment: `x++` is in else section, i believe it should not be part of if or else section

Comment: You also need to enclose the entire `for` block in brackets (C# does not use indentation to define blocks)

Comment: Also please re-read [mre] guidance on posting code - there is a lot of extra code not necessary to demonstrate the problem - i.e. reading from console is unrelated, that bogus empty statement in `else` clause as @ikegami pointed out is not needed, and generally auto-formatting the code would help.

Comment: Learn to embrace the debugger - step through the code line by line, look at variable values, and see where your logic fails.

Comment: @sairfan, No, it's not in the `else`. See the semi-colon?

Comment: Debugging your code **[using the awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** is an essential skill because it will help you learn how code you write *actually* executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most of the erroros are that you are lacking some {} and ()

```
 String input = Console.ReadLine();

        int number;

        int.TryParse(input, out number);

        for (int x = 1; x <= number; ++x)
        {
            if ((x % 3) == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);

            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Re "*you are lacking some [...] ()*", No. `x % 3 == 0` was fine. `%` has higher precedence than `==`.

Comment: Oh true, im just so used to that, my bad.